# How can I write cleanly __init__ method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, init

I want write cleanly **init** method in **python**.

my **init** method is very long and dirty.

I don't know how can clean it.

and its my dirty code:

```
class Detect:
    """Class to show frames"""

    def __init__(self,
                 main_target,
                 target_object,
                 camera,
                 sms_class,
                 qr_code_class,
                 cuda="CPU"):
        self.main_target = main_target
        self.target_object = target_object
        self.camera = camera
        self.sms_class = sms_class
        self.qr_code_class = qr_code_class
        self.cuda = cuda

        self.classes_names = []
        self.previous_time = 0
        self.authorised = True
        self.first_time = 0
        self.first_detect_time = 0
        self.color = (255, 0, 255)
        self.capture = cv.VideoCapture(self.camera)
        self.conf_threshold = 0.5
        self.nms_threshold = 0.3
```

Comment: What do you mean "reduce variable"?

Comment: What is dirty here? If you are not happy with many variables,  then just remove them. If you need all of them, and you spend one line on each, then why do you consider this is dirty?

Comment: @khelwood I mean to write it cleanly

Comment: @trincot I mean to write it cleanly

Comment: That is saying the same thing. What is not clean about it? Please explain what you see as a *problem*?

Comment: @trincot a senior python programmer see my code, and said its very dirty and long

Comment: They probably refer to the complete code and the way you have tried to solve the higher level problem. Usually classes should be relatively small. But we cannot suggest anything without knowing which problem you try to solve, and what the larger context is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about it, one is to define a base class and assign all those default values in the base class, and inherit `Detect` from it. I've even further reduced the first part using `**kwargs` and `setattr` method:

```py
class BaseDetect:
    def __init__(self):
        self.classes_names = []
        self.previous_time = 0
        self.authorised = True
        self.first_time = 0
        self.first_detect_time = 0
        self.color = (255, 0, 255)
        self.conf_threshold = 0.5
        self.nms_threshold = 0.3


class Detect(BaseDetect):
    """Class to show frames"""
    def __init__(self, cuda = "CPU", **kwargs):
        self.cuda = cuda
        super().__init__()
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        
        self.capture = cv.VideoCapture(self.camera)
```

It still has those codes of course but doesn't the child class look much cleaner now? Also, if those values are static and not going to change, it's just better to make them class variable, or global constants. That's also something you can try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use python dataclasses for this :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

which would result in something like this

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, Any, Tuple


@dataclass
class Detect:
    """Class to show frames"""
    main_target: str
    target_object: str
    camera: str
    sms_class: Any
    qr_code_class: Any
    cuda: str

    classes_names: List = field(default_factory=list)
    previous_time: int = 0
    authorised: bool = True
    first_time: int = 0
    first_detect_time: int = 0
    color: Tuple[int] = (255, 0, 255)
    conf_threshold: float = 0.5
    nms_threshold: float = 0.3

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.capture = cv.VideoCapture(self.camera)
```

Answer (score 0):

They are there for some reasons right? It's normal for your class instances to have a lot of attributes.

But if you have inheritance hierarchy in your design, you can initialize them in the parents. It's makes the children's `__init__` cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

You can place some of your attributes outside `__init__`:

```
class Detect:
    """Class to show frames"""
    classes_names = []
    previous_time = 0
    authorised = True
    first_time = 0
    first_detect_time = 0
    color = (255, 0, 255)
    capture = cv.VideoCapture(self.camera)
    conf_threshold = 0.5
    nms_threshold = 0.3


    def __init__(self,
             main_target,
             target_object,
             camera,
             sms_class,
             qr_code_class,
             cuda="CPU"):
        self.main_target = main_target
        self.target_object = target_object
        self.camera = camera
        self.sms_class = sms_class
        self.qr_code_class = qr_code_class
        self.cuda = cuda
```